# new elements not seen by jQuery .on() method

Tags: jquery

I try to add a div after the change of file input

my HTML code

```
<div class="form-group product-color">
    <div>
        <label>Color:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Color name"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Size:</label>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> S
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> M
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> L
          </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> XL
          </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> XXL
          </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Color Image:</label>
        <input type="file" class="input-lg product-img" multiple=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my jQuery code is

```
$(".product-color").on('change', 'input[type=file]', function () {
    var  test = $(this).closest('.product-color').clone();
    $(this).closest('.product-color').after(test);
});
```

but the problem is that new elements are not seen by the .on() method and the .after() function is applied only to the first div.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the event to the `document` element instead of `.product-color` element.

```
$(document).on('change', '.product-color input[type=file]', function () {
var  test = $(this).closest('.product-color').clone();
    $(this).closest('.product-color').after(test);
});
```

This is because you're cloning the `.product-color` element. So newly created elements won't have the event bound to them

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/10omL8a2/)

Answer (score 2):

Try adjusting `test` to `$(this).closest('.product-color');` ; add `true` as parameter to `.clone()` to preserve attached `change` event at cloned `".product-color"` elements ; call `test.after(test.clone(true));` at next line

```js
$(".product-color").on('change', 'input[type=file]', function () {
    var  test = $(this).closest('.product-color');
    test.after(test.clone(true));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group product-color">
    <div>
        <label>Color:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Color name"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Size:</label>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> S
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> M
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> L
          </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> XL
          </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> XXL
          </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Color Image:</label>
        <input type="file" class="input-lg product-img" multiple=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works also but after changing $(".product-color").on by $(document).on

Comment: @IBMdig _" 
it works also but after changing $(".product-color").on by $(document).on"_ Same result should be returned by utilizing `.clone(true)` , see http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents. Tried selecting file at second cloned `input` element at stacksnippets ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no element which is a parent of `$(".product-color")` in your HTML. Try to insert your HTML after the last `$(".product-color")` using [**last()**](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

```
$(".product-color").on('change', 'input[type=file]', function () {
    var test = $(this).closest('.product-color').clone();
    $(".product-color").last().after(test);
});
```